# AWS REST Request

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

Below is my request body. When I hit the request using postman it throws forbidden with 403 error code but when I remove the `"paymentOkUrl": "https://ei-prelive.dasitha.com:8289/general/api-gateway/v1/upad/pb/termUrl"`  from request body it executes successfully. I found it blocks any thing starts from "https://". I am using AWS ECS (with EC2) to host my springboot app.

I am new to AWS can anyone tell me what should I change in the aws configurations to solve this problem.

**Request:**

```
{
    "paymentProvider": "ELAVON_REALEX",
    "systemId": "30",
    "orderId": "26518203_3afb594b-f25e-40de-bca2-650a1a234b53",
    "amount": "14100",
    "currencyCode": "GBP",
    "cardDetails": {
        "cardType": "MASTERCARD",
        "cardNumber": "5269275301730688",
        "expiryDate": "0424",
        "cardHolderName": "Perera H T P M"
    },
    "paymentOkUrl": "https://ei-prelive.dasitha.com:8289/general/api-gateway/v1/upad/pb/termUrl"
}
```

**Response:**

{403 Forbidden}

Comment: I removed the " : " mark from " https://" then also its working .. where can I remove filter for colone.

Comment: Hey, could you provide more information & rethink how you ask your question, I'm failing how to see this question being linked to Java at all, apart from the fact that you've mentioned 'springboot'.